# Reusing code for several UI-Select in angular app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

How can I reuse code if i have more than one ui-select in my angular app and all dealing with different remote API to show options?

With reference to [AngularJS Wrapping a ui-select in a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647530/angularjs-wrapping-a-ui-select-in-a-custom-directive), I've got an idea that wrapping ui-select in custom diretive will help to reuese code but again I will have to write different code for controller to call different API endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed the answer of @Floc and managed to make a custom reusable directive.If someone is stuck with same problem then they can refer this code.

## Directive

```
  app.directive('tagInput',function($http){
  return{
  restrict : 'E',
  templateUrl : 'tag-input.html',
  scope:{
    placeholder : '@',
    ngModel : '='    
  },
  link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
  scope.addresses = [];
  scope.refreshAddresses = function(address){
    var params = {address:address,sensor:false};
    return $http.get(attrs.url,{params:params})
      .then(function(response){
        scope.addresses = response.data.results[0].address_components;
      })
     }
   }
  }
  })
```

## template

```
<ui-select style="width:50%"  ng-model="$parent.ngModel" theme="select2">
<ui-select-match placeholder="{{placeholder}}">{{$select.selected.long_name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index" refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)" refresh-delay="0" >
     <span ng-bind-html="address.long_name| highlight: $select.search"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

And pass required parameters here(in my case it is url and placeholder)

```
<tag-input url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json" placeholder="hello"></tag-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You don't have to code different controllers. If all the differents API return the same objects structures you just have to add a binding attribute to your custom directive giving the API url. Then, the controller of your custom directive will be able to use it.

**2)** Otherwise, you will have to create an object or interface for the returning data and a single controller that can deal with the different APIs.

**3)** Or, you can also create your custom directive with a binding attribute that is a factory to your objects. Then, you will have to give the factory method to your directive when you want to use it.

If you don't know about binding attributes, [check this](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750).